# Write two or more instructions in one line with PHP

Tags: php

I have a very simple question for you guys.
After deep researches, I've found nothing useful to get a good answer.

I just really like to know the way to write multiple instructions/commands in the same line, with PHP.
Just to be clear, this:

```
<?php
  if (true) {
    echo "First,";
    echo " second";
    echo " and third.";
  }
?>
```

shoud become this:

```
<?php
  if (true)
    echo "First," & echo " second" & echo " and third";
?>
```

So, the script above can execute three operations in one line of code.
I tried to use the "&" sign to append more instructions in the same line and it seems it works...
Is this the correct way to do what I want to do? May this cause any problems?

Thanks!

PS: the "echo" instruction is just as example (I know that you can merge strings just using the dot (.) sign

Comment: I don't understand the question. Multiple echo's without breaks will appear on the same page.

Comment: Eh... remove the newlines from your original text?

Comment: `echo`ing uses the `.` for concatenation. Other than that, why do you want to run multiple commands on one line? What's wrong with having them on multiple lines?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Well basically the semi-column is the "end of instruction" indicator , so you could just write anything on 1 line as long as you separate it with semi-column. But writing stuff on 1 line makes your code less readable...

Comment: I really dont get how this is usefull.

Comment: I need to do that to clear my code. I don't need this to write multiple "echos" (as I said, in this case I can use the dot (.) to concatenate strings).

Comment: Are you asking about conditional operator `?:` Something like `echo true ? 'True' : 'False'`

Comment: Code typically doesn't get "clearer" by mushing it together. On the contrary.

Comment: You never need so many `echos` anyways. Use them when you need to inject variables inside HTML, but don't use it to create the usual pile of `echo <div>`, please.

Comment: @Roberto Perhaps you should replace your example code with `foo(); bar(); baz();`. The choice of `echo` seems to cause a lot of confusion here. Though `foo() & bar() & baz()` would actually happen to work, only `echo` happens to not work here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP puts no significance on a line break at all. All you need to do is remove the line break, everything else can stay exactly the same:

```
<?php if (true) { echo "First,"; echo " second"; echo " and third."; } ?>
```

The statements are already terminated and separated by `;`.

Comment: I think this answer is really stupid, but maybe the question is even more stupid... Yeah, to put multiple instructions in one line I can just use brackets without line breaks. I have to vote this answer as the better one... Thanks! :)
(and sorry to others if I couldn't be as clear as I expected)

Comment: And you don't even need the brackets. They're just needed to keep the same semantics for the `if` statement. `if` executes *one statement* following it, `{}` *groups* several statements into one. Specifically for `echo` @Marc's syntax may be preferable, but for anything else brackets are.

Comment: Neither the question nor this answer are stupid. PHP statements (aka instructions) are [terminated by `;`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php). PHP statement groups are [enclosed by curly braces](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php). A PHP file may have multiple statements on one line; there is no need to have a line break between them. (However, I can't find this stated explicitly in the PHP Manual.)

Answer (score 3):

No. It's not correct. `echo` is not a function, and is not something you can `&` together like that. It does, however, support comma-separated "arguments", so something like

```
echo 'first', 'second', 'third';
```

is entirely possible and totally valid PHP code.

Even if the `&` version was possible, you'd actually be LOSING efficiency, because you're doing 3 echo calls, and then trying to combine their non-existence return values. e.g. you'd be turning 3 operations into **5**.

Comment: Was just about to answer this but wasn't sure if there was an even simpler way.

Comment: Ok so it's not correct using the "&" operator to combine multiple operations.

Comment: `&` is the bitwise-AND operator. It's not something you'd use in this kind of context at all. Like I said... `echo` has no return value, so you'd be doing `nothing AND nothing AND nothing`, which is pointless.